# Android get location with GPS doesn't work

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

I'm trying to get the current location via GPS like this:

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

and in the onLocationChanged method of the LocationListener I do this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null){
        title.setText("Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+"\nLong: "+location.getLongitude());
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }else Log.e("Location", "null");
}
```

but on my phone (API 4.4.2) the onLocationChanged method is never called.

So if I try it with

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

everything works fine. Does anyone now what the problem with GPS is? I despair soon, because there are so many answers here on stackoverflow about GPS problems but nothing solved my problem..

Comment: The most common problems with requesting GPS are: 1. The GPS/Fine location setting is turned off in Settings, or 2. Your phone cannot see the sky and hence cannot get a GPS fix. Are you able to get a GPS fix in other apps (like Maps)?

Comment: you're right my GPS connection was to bad for the request, but it was good enough for google maps.